# Can I get console logs from my iPhone app testers?

Tags: iphone, testing

I am testing my iPhone app with some people who install it through iTunes together with the mobile provision file that I give them. Apple has good instructions for how to get crash logs from these people, but is it also possible to get console logs from their devices? I do not have physical access to these people, otherwise I could connect their device to my computer and see the console log in Organizer. I would like to give them instructions to get me their console logs, but there doesn't seem to be a way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apple's iPhone Configuration Utility (available at http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/ ) for both Mac and PC allows your users to capture log information and send it to you.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed, didn't realize it's also usable for end users, thought it's for enterprise admin only.

Comment: You can download iPhone Configuration Utility 3.5 (Mac) here: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US Please note, that you currently cannot download Apple Configurator for Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9) via the Mac App Store (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12), because it requires Mac OS X Yosemite. So use the above iPhone Configuration Utility instead.

Comment: Is available at the Apple Store. https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12

Comment: I'm getting "The item you've requested is not currently available in the U.S. store". So far, most of the answers on how to get console messages while testing with TestFlight seems to be outdated. Anyone knows a simple and good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use the iOS Console Kit from [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/consolekit/id648875678?ls=1&mt=8)

Comment: God, its damn good utility! Sometimes IPhone Configuration Utility crash @ windows 7. Its will help you!

Comment: Doesn't seem to support iOS7+

Comment: iOS7 onwards Apple has removed access to console logs for other applications.