# Possible to write swift println logs into file too?

Tags: swift, logging

Is it an easy way to write logs into a text file too? I need a crash log to analyse when something went wrong. But I already use println al around in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `String.writeToFile(<#path: String#>, atomically: <#Bool#>, encoding: <#NSStringEncoding#>, error: <#NSErrorPointer#>)`

You could add this:

```
#if DEBUG
func println(s:String) {
  var error:NSError? = nil
  let path = "/Users/<me>/dump.txt"
  var dump = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
  "\(dump)\n\(s)".writeToFile(path, atomically:true, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding, error:&error)
}
#endif
```

See the #if DEBUG answer on SO how to use this compiler flag.

Comment: It would be more effective to open a file for appending, instead of re-reading and -writing the entire contents for each println() ...

Comment: Yes sure. This was a hot shot, but performance isn't in question here and you can change that anyways if you like easily.

Answer (score 4):

For swift 3, change Thomas Killan's code like this

```
func println(s:String) {
    let path = "/Users/<me>/dump.txt"
    var dump = ""
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path) {
        dump =  try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    do {
        // Write to the file
        try  "\(dump)\n\(s)".write(toFile: path, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed writing to log file: \(path), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, using a `println()`-based solution will not result in output being captured by the Apple System Log (ASL).

The ASL is the logging facility provided by the Mac OS and iOS that is used by `NSLog()` (and on a Mac is visible through the Console application). Because `NSLog()` uses ASL, log entries recorded by `NSLog()` will be visible through the device console. Messages logged through `println()` will not be captured in ASL, and as a result, provide no opportunity to go back to the console for diagnostic purposes after something has happened.

[The CleanroomLogger open-source project](https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomLogger) provides an extensible Swift API that you can use to do what you want. You would just implement a `LogRecorder` and specify it in the configuration in addition to the `ASLLogRecorder`.

Answer (score 1):

I modified a little your function to be global and add to save a log per day.

```
public func debugPrint(s:String)
{
  var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
  let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
  let dateString = formatter.string(from: Date())
  let fileName = "\(dateString).log"
  let logFilePath = (documentsDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
  var dump = ""

  if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: logFilePath) {
      dump =  try! String(contentsOfFile: logFilePath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
  }

  do {
      // Write to the file
      try  "\(dump)\n\(Date()):\(s)".write(toFile: logFilePath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
      
  } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Failed writing to log file: \(logFilePath), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
  }
}
```