# iOS Swift - How to save Console Outputs as text files (i.e. println(), NSLog() )

Tags: swift, logging

I'm currently trying to set up a simple logger for my application, and figured that i'd be much more convenient if I can just `NSLog()` onto a text file. Is there a simple method to do this?

Comment: for NSLog use this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097424/logging-data-on-device-and-retrieving-the-log/41741076#41741076

Comment: For just save the outputs as File use this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114110/possible-to-write-swift-println-logs-into-file-too/41740777#41740777

Answer (score 1):

You could use ASL, the direct counterpart of syslog that write directly to text file.

[Some example code](https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/0ded6cd153f61c627226)

[Useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271528/how-to-nslog-into-a-file)

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html)