# Best Firebase IOS Debug techniques

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I am developing an App using Firebase Analytics for Swift IOS

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

My understanding is that it is not possible to confirm Firebase events are sent in real time unless I use BigQuery which I do not have access to.

For QA purposes I would like to write Firebase logging to a text file rather than to console.

Is it possible to send all output with flag set

```
-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
```

to a text file which could then be more easily checked than using an HTTP Sniffer.

---- Update -----

This is the code I used from Alex's idea, his link did not include Swift 3 solution which has a few updated variables.

```
func redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder() {
    let file = "log.txt"
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let logFileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
        print("log:\(logFileURL)")

        logFileURL.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation {
            _ = freopen($0, "a+", stderr)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that flag in development and follow the steps in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097424/logging-data-on-device-and-retrieving-the-log) to output to a file.