# How to write Application Logs to File and get them

Tags: ios, swift, logging, oslog

I´m taking baby steps in iOS development and searching for a method to use logging in iOS.

I found these docs about logging with swift 3 : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging#1682426

The Docs say that the logs aren´t saved on disk. What is the typical way to get the logs and process the file?

Comment: i guess you want to get the logs as file like a CrashReporter am I right? In that case there are a couple of pods which can archive this. [PLCrashReporter](https://www.plcrashreporter.org/) is one I am using in one of my projects. It prints the logfiles into a file and makes an report which will be sent to a specific server.

Comment: I want to logs parameters and runtime behavior with os.log like in the docs. In near future I want to collect those logs and send them elsewhere. But I´m looking for a clean swift in code approach and not a lib.

Answer (score 27):

put this file to your project

```
//
//  log.swift
//  logtest
//

import Foundation

struct Log: TextOutputStream {

    func write(_ string: String) {
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let log = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("log.txt")
        if let handle = try? FileHandle(forWritingTo: log) {
            handle.seekToEndOfFile()
            handle.write(string.data(using: .utf8)!)
            handle.closeFile()
        } else {
            try? string.data(using: .utf8)?.write(to: log)
        }
    }
}

var logger = Log()
```

and if you need something to be logged, just use print function like

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        print("started:", Date(), to: &logger)
        return true
    }
```

or

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    print(#file, #function, "my own text", 1, [1,2], to: &logger)
}
```

in your application's 'Documents' folder you could find 'log.txt' file which you could examine later.

while running my test application twice, the content looks like

```
started: 2017-06-14 09:58:58 +0000
/Users/ivo_vacek/Documents/logtest/logtest/ViewController.swift viewDidLoad() my own text 1 [1, 2]
started: 2017-06-14 09:59:15 +0000
/Users/ivo_vacek/Documents/logtest/logtest/ViewController.swift viewDidLoad() my own text 1 [1, 2]
```

if you don't like 'globals' define Log as singletone class

```
class Log: TextOutputStream {

    func write(_ string: String) {
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let log = fm.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("log.txt")
        if let handle = try? FileHandle(forWritingTo: log) {
            handle.seekToEndOfFile()
            handle.write(string.data(using: .utf8)!)
            handle.closeFile()
        } else {
            try? string.data(using: .utf8)?.write(to: log)
        }
    }
    static var log: Log = Log()
    private init() {} // we are sure, nobody else could create it
}
```

and use it like

```
print("started:", Date(), to: &Log.log)
```

Comment: okey yeah. this is a approach but why cant I use the os.log framework? I I mean it contains a LogLevel and so on. I have one open Question what means the '&' in front of Log.log?

Comment: @Offset OSLog is available only on iOS 10.0+, macOS 10.12+, tvOS 10.0+, watchOS 3.0+, Unknown SDK 8.0+. & works as an inout to make the variable an in-out parameter. To use OSLog import os to your files

Comment: okay just to be clear. OSLog is only for debugging? I cant write to file or can be used as a file? I Think its very confusing. Even more there´s a NSLog which is available for all versions.  So to sum up : Either I write my own logger (like above) or use a third party lib?

Comment: @Offset up to you :-), there is not enough information (at least I don't have) to effectively use OSLog. For using NSLog/ NSLogv see 'man 3 asl'. If you want to direct output elsewhere, you need to use a custom logging facility.

Comment: @user3441734 the same way, like any other .txt files, there is a lot of examples around

Comment: Is there anyway to simply use logs created by calls to `os_log` and zip them and email them? Currently I'm only aware of the sysdiagnose approach...

Comment: @user3441734 how to fetch log.txt file?

Comment: You can find the log file here using this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6121613/1759443

Comment: I got the following text as a log: "started app: 2022-02-14 16:01:19 +0000". How can I get the following text "2022-02-14 16:01:19 +0000 - started app" ? I want to see the date in the first place.

Comment: On device, where file is saved? I wan to manage it anda send

Answer (score 11):

Swift 3.0 version

Create a new swift file "TextLog.swift" in your project

```
import Foundation

struct TextLog: TextOutputStream {

    /// Appends the given string to the stream.
    mutating func write(_ string: String) {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask)
        let documentDirectoryPath = paths.first!
        let log = documentDirectoryPath.appendingPathComponent("log.txt")

        do {
            let handle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: log)
            handle.seekToEndOfFile()
            handle.write(string.data(using: .utf8)!)
            handle.closeFile()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            do {
                try string.data(using: .utf8)?.write(to: log)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Initialize the logger at bottom in the AppDelegate.swift file

```
var textLog = TextLog()
```

Use it anywhere in the application like below

```
textLog.write("hello")
```

Comment: where I can see this log file In our Device?

Comment: @AnupGupta, You can find it here ~/Library/Containers/YOU_APP_BUNDLE_ID/Data/Documents

Comment: /Users/pradeepkumar/Library/Containers/YOU_APP_BUNDLE_ID/Data/Documents/Qandle/

Comment: I struggled where to find it, but this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6121613/1759443

Answer (score 3):

> The Docs say that the logs aren´t saved on disk. What is the typical way to get the logs and process the file?

I'm not sure if this was true at some point and changed, but [the current documentation you linked to](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging#1682426) *does* say logs are saved on disk:

> This system centralizes the storage of log data in memory and on disk, rather than writing that data to a text-based log file.

Specifically, you can find this table in [a recommended article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code):

[image]

> You can override the default storage behavior of each log level using tools or custom configuration profiles. For more information on how to do so, see [Customizing Logging Behavior While Debugging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/customizing_logging_behavior_while_debugging)

Here's [an example in the article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code) of how to use the logger (swift):

```swift
if #available(OSX 11.0, *) {
   // Log a message to the default log and default log level.
   let defaultLog = Logger()
   defaultLog.log("This is a default message.")
            
   // Log a message to the default log and debug log level
   defaultLog.debug("This is a debug message.")


   // Log an error to a custom log object.
   let customLog = Logger(subsystem: "com.your_company.your_subsystem", 
          category: "your_category_name")
   customLog.error("An error occurred!")
} else {
   // Log a message to the default log and default log level.
   os_log("This is a default message.")
            
   // Log a message to the default log and debug log level
   os_log("This is a debug message.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            
   // Log an error to a custom log object.
   let customLog = OSLog(subsystem: "com.your_company.your_subsystem", 
            category: "your_category_name")
   os_log("An error occurred!", log: customLog, type: .error)
}
```

As far as I can tell, there's no need to use the other answers (anymore?)

Comment: The OP is also asking about 'how to get them'. Your answer would benefit more if you discuss OSLogStore & Sysdiagnose as well

Comment: @Honey your comment helped me, because I've been trying to figure that out, too. The documentation says the unified logging system is useful for "When you are unable to attach a debugger to the app, such as when you’re diagnosing problems on a user’s machine," but as far as I can tell, doesn't explain anywhere how to do this. I'll look into those two concepts and update my answer.

Comment: @Honey I've been searching for a whole hour and I can't figure out how to use OSLogStore. The most informative thing I've found is this article: https://steipete.com/posts/logging-in-swift but I still don't know how to use OSLogStore after reading it, nor do I understand why you'd need to: the documentation I linked to above doesn't mention it anywhere yet, as that table shows, it still logs to disk.

Comment: @Honey OSLogStore isn't mentioned in the official Logger docs either: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger

Comment: Click any instruction to see docs for trigger sysdiagnose from [here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/). Though I recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588673/how-can-i-retrieve-messages-logged-with-os-log-from-ipad-iphone) way. I haven't used OSLogStore, but its benefits is 1. you can query them with certain predicates as opposed to a sysdiagnose that queries ALL oslogs of all apps. 2. You can save them to disk and or ask users to email it I believe. 3. Docs are [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/oslog/oslogstore/3204125-getentries)

Comment: @Honey cool thank you for that information. I'm still confused about how the `Logger` comes into play though. Do `Logger`s magically know where to write on disk and `OSLogStore` magically knows where to read it from?

Comment: I've used oslog/Logger before. And you never specify where it should log to. So my assumption is that Yes it magically logs and retrieves

Answer (score 2):

Simple way!

```
func createLogFile() {
   guard let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first else {
            return
   }
   let fileName = "\(Date()).log"
   let logFilePath = (documentsDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
   freopen(logFilePath.cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii), "a+", stderr)
}
```

Now call this method on viewDidLoad

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createLogFile()
        NSLog("First Log")
        NSLog("Second Log")
    }
}
```

Goto the simulator application directory and check the logs.

[image]

NOTE: Only ***NSLog*** will work this way. ***Print***, ***debugPrint*** will not work.