# iOS os.log from an app deployed on device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, logging

I am using new `os.log` thing for logging in my app as follows:

```
import os.log

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // a bunch of methods
}

extension OSLog {
    static let ui = OSLog(subsystem: "io.my.app", category: "ui")
}

extension ViewController {        
    func upload(locations: [LocationProtocol]) {
        os_log("Sending locations to server", log: .ui, type: .debug)
        self.server_api.send(locations)
    }
}
```

The logs are shown in `Console.app` as expected when I am debugging the app from Xcode. But is it possible to somehow retrieve logged strings from an app's instance deployed on a device? I am testing my app "in the field", away from the laptop, and wanted to dump gathered logs into a text file.

Do I need to configure loggers somehow to persistently store logs, or it is only possible to get crash reports from a deployed app?

> Note: I am using **Swift 4 / Xcode 9+**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537133/how-to-write-application-logs-to-file-and-get-them

Comment: According to online info, the `os_log` logs are stored in _/var/db/diagnostics/_ on the device and you can retrieve them from there later and open them in the Console. But I have not tried this myself.

Comment: @matt But it seems this guy creates a custom solution to manually write logs into a specific file. I would like to use `os.log` instead =)

Comment: @matt Interesting enough that there is no _/var/db/diagnostics/_ path in app's container.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you can solve this with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13303081/2136375

To summarize:

### Step 1

Add to the following code to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to enable the app to log to a file:

```
var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let deviceName = UIDevice.current.name
let fileName = "\(deviceName) - \(Date()).log"
let logFilePath = (documentsDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent(fileName) freopen(logFilePath.cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii)!, "a+", stderr)
```

### Step 2

In the `info.plist` add:

#### Alt 1

As property list item:

"Application supports iTunes file sharing" and set to YES.

#### Alt 2

As source code:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: This works great. Just import os, and use os_log. Download the app's container, or use iTunes file sharing.