# Apple Recommended Logging approach for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-logging, oslog

## Note:

This is not a duplicate of the linked questions

## Goal:

- I am not looking for a `print` vs `NSLog` differences
- In fact I don't want to use either of them (presently using `print`)
- I am looking for an Apple recommended way, just can't seem to find the command / documentation, I just know it exists.

## Present implementation:

Presently I am using `print` statements with some global functions

## Question

1. What is the recommended way / approach to handle errors (I don't want to use NSLog as they would write into the device's console)
2. This is only for debugging purposes during development

Comment: Make sure you check `os.log`. You can use its results during debug and release. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45353818/5175709)

Comment: This seems like a great opportunity to incorporate open source software like [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack), which has macros like `DDLogError`, `DDLogWarn`, `DDLogInfo`, etc.

Comment: @Honey `os.log` seems interesting, thanks, could you post it as an answer, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: For now you can use https://github.com/apple/swift-log

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Take a look at [`os_log`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging). It offers all the things you're looking for.

### NEW STUFF

Also the more easier to use [Logger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger/3551621-init) API available since iOS14. See [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/ios-14s-new-logger-api-vs-oslog-ef88bb2ec237) as well

Since iOS15 you can also retrieve the logs using [`OSLogStore`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/oslog/oslogstore) . See [here](https://steipete.com/posts/logging-in-swift/).

Also see [Acquiring Crash Reports and Diagnostic Logs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/acquiring-crash-reports-and-diagnostic-logs)

---

**Disclaimer:**

I highly recommend you see [this thread from Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/custom-string-interpolation-and-compile-time-interpretation-applied-to-logging/18799/10). tl;dr

Even though it's' Apple's recommendation, its usage is debated due to concerns about retrieving logs:

- retrieving logs is not a trivial process. It's actually difficult. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588673/how-can-i-retrieve-messages-logged-with-os-log-from-ipad-iphone)
- For most users the log file can be 100-300 Mbs. Which makes it hard to send.

It's great for debugging during development, but laborious to trigger, retrieve, send by your app users.

---

**Example:**

```
let customLog = OSLog(subsystem: "com.your_company.your_subsystem_name", category: "Category")
os_log("This is info that may be helpful during development or debugging.", log: customLog, type: .debug)
```

Some great references:

- [WWDC 2016 Unified Logging and Tracing](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/).
- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25951564/5175709) by Rob. He discusses that `NSLog` is deprecated and some of the benefits of using the new  `os_log` library.
- You can also get the logs from using the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353818/how-can-i-open-view-logs). Make sure you see **?** answers.

The reason `os_log` is so powerful is because:

- offers different log levels
- has different categories
- `private` and `public` logs
- it's lightweight and built by Apple. Doesn't require pods
- unlike `print` which is only available during debugging, `os_log` can be used to peek into a released app (in realtime) and view the logs in the console app.

[image]

This is great for observing application life cycle changes free of the [greedy Xcode](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14855) i.e. if you’re debugging while connected to Xcode , then Xcode doesn’t allow the app to be put in a suspended state...

---

**Note:** `os_log` is only available to +iOS10

There are new videos as well from WWDC 2018 and 2019, but have a higher focus on `os_signpost`. See:

- [WWDC 2018 - Measuring Performance Using Logging](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/405/)
- [WWDC 2019 - Getting Started with Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/)
- [WWDC 2019 - Developing a Great Profiling Experience](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/414/)

Comment: Hello , how to read os_log after release my app ??

Comment: You either need the actual device or the sysdiagnose. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353818/how-can-i-open-view-ios-oslogs-stored-on-device/45381965#45381965)

Comment: thank you , Can users send it to me via mail? like log.txt file ??

Comment: It would be 100-300Mb file. So no. They can use Dropbox. But the process of creating a sysdiagnose and sending it is not something most users are capable of. I actually wonder which users Apple thinks will use this...

Comment: One problem with using os_log is that you cannot pass dynamic strings so you can't hide it inside your own debug function taking params from outside. You have to use it explicitly in your code, eg:
os_log("User %{PRIVATE}@ logged in", log: OSLog.userFlow, type: .info, username)
there's 12/2018 proposal to alleviate this
 https://forums.swift.org/t/custom-string-interpolation-and-compile-time-interpretation-applied-to-logging/18799/7