# Xcode 9.3 there is no way to see live device logs

Tags: ios, xcode9.3

Is there any hidden button to see the live device logs in Xcode 9.3 or apple is forcing us to go to console to see device logs it can also be a bug.

I cannot see any more a small arrow at bottom that we used to have in Devices and Simulator tab of Xcode.

Please refer screen attached.[image]

Answer (score 21):

In Xcode 9.3 device logs are moved to new location.To get on the new screen you have to navigate through Xcode -> Windows -> Device & Simulators.On device and simulators screen there is a new button added saying open console.

[image]

Click on an open console button, then you will be navigated to a new screen.I believe here you will get device logs at runtime.

[image: Console Log Screen]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as mentioned in my question is apple forcing us now to use console, we are just opening console application now from Xcode.

Comment: Also, now there is noway to export live logs which we were able to do it in previous versions. You have to select the logs to export them.

Answer (score 3):

Simply,

```
1. Xcode -> Windows -> Device & Simulators
2. Click: Open Console
```

It will start showing logs.

> **Important:**

For `Swift` project `print(" ")/debugPrint(" ")` logs won't show here.
Use `NSLog("Something")` to get in **console** application.

Answer (score 1):

The other (incorrectly downvoted) answer is correct. When I click the Console button in the Devices window...

[image]

...I see the device's live console messages scrolling by in the Console app:

[image]

Comment: Hey Matt thanks for the answer, if we do this there is noway to export live logs which we were able to do it in previous versions. you have to select the logs to export.

Comment: Console app lets you filter the logs. It is much _more_ powerful.

Comment: I also agree with Matt on how much powerful and flexible to use console app.There are multiple filter parameters to choose such as PID, Date & Time, Thread ID and much more.

Comment: Two steps forward, one step back. There is no good way to export the logs to a file

Answer (score 0):

My logs will randomly disappear - usually when the app crashes. If I delete the app from the device, then the logs return on next build.