# How to get Device Logs in a text file from NSlog using Objective c?

Tags: objective-c, json, nslog

I'm getting **json data** in my **NSlog in Xcode** using following code

```
NSString *jsonStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:activityData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Sync Json:%@",jsonStr);
```

So if I have to get the same **json data** in **my device log** which can be sent as a text file as an email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging data on device and retrieving the log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097424/logging-data-on-device-and-retrieving-the-log)

Comment: What “device log” are you talking about? If you want to write to a file, write to it. There is no log file that you can retrieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code to fix my issue

```
[[DBHelper getSharedInstance] AddLogFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sync Json:%@",jsonStr]];
```

which sends the NSLog to my device log file.

Answer (score 0):

NSLogs will be in your device logs when building in release mode (production app). No further action is required by you.