# Logging data on device and retrieving the log from remote device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I copied the title from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097424/logging-data-on-device-and-retrieving-the-log) as I have the same question, I went through the answers on that post, however, all of them require me to have physical access to the device. My question is how do I log something like an NSString on my clients' device which I don't have access to and then retrieve those logs. Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: which logs you want, error logs?

Comment: Not really, I just want to have a simple NSString.

Comment: As we are added one API which sends us all logs which occurs when a customer uses App. So that will know which error comes. we also send logs as a string. We also keep creating a log file on each device so that all logs added in that, when customer raised some issue then we take that file.

Comment: Is that your own private API or something available on the internet, if Yes let me know the name.

Comment: Its our own private API.