# How can I access the Console Output for an App store deployed app?

Tags: ios, console, diagnostics

I understand that there is an option for an iOS app user to share a crash report via Diagnostics & usage data. But I am faced with a problem where the app doesn't actually crash but looks like it's freezing on a particular screen and it doesn't happen for all users, only a few.

So is there an option for the affected user to share only the Console Output or for me to directly view the Console output through any means?

Also I am fairly certain that the app isn't freezing, rather it doesn't proceed after a screen due to Core Data model incompatibility issue. But I need to confirm if this is indeed the cause, hence the need for the user's Console output for this particular app.

**Edit**: To clarify, I have gone through quite a few posts on this topic but what I am looking for is an elegant and simple way for the app users to share the app's console output.

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097424/logging-data-on-device-and-retrieving-the-log

Comment: Thanks for the link @NamitGupta. I have gone through quite a few questions already but what I am looking for is a more elegant or Apple-provided solution, as I would like to avoid asking the app users to go through all that trouble.