# Is “NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled” still alive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, logging, environment-variables

I’m trying to see how `NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled` log looks like.

I created a new single-view iOS project, set `NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled` to `YES`:
[image]

And after running an app, viewed `AppData/tmp` folder inside an app’s folder:
[image]

There’re no files. 
How to check if this variable is still working, or which possibility can be used now?

**UPD**:

As is said in the link provided by @SaurabhJain, the logging is possible only on Simulator. 
I've tried it, and while there still weren't files in `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/(SIMULATORID)/data/Containers/Data/Application/(APPLICATIONID)`, there was file like `launches.2019-04-05.17.15.02.log` in `/tmp`. 
 But this file was created also when `NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled` was `NO`, and it's content is about the same: I don't see the names of functions called. 
 
So I can't make it work even in Simulator.

Comment: have look this http://qaru.site/questions/2488359/nsobjcmessageloggingenabled-with-iphone-30

Comment: @SaurabhJain Thanks, it still doesn't work, please see my update.

Comment: are you using core-data?

Comment: @SaurabhJain No

Comment: Have look this URL for logs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097424/logging-data-on-device-and-retrieving-the-log

Comment: @SaurabhJain Thanks, I'll look.