# How do I access "iTunes Sharing" files in Catalina?

Tags: ios, macos-catalina

Prior to Catalina, one possibility for retrieving on-device logs for an app was to write to a file in a particular location, with the "Application supports iTunes file sharing" plist key set to true.

(see [Logging data on device and retrieving the log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097424/logging-data-on-device-and-retrieving-the-log) for examples)

Prior macos 10.15 Catalina, the user would plug in their phone, open iTunes, and find the app and download the files through iTunes directly.

How do I access the files I could previously retrieve through iTunes sharing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect an iOS device to Catalina, it will appear as a volume in Finder. Simply click on it and select the "files" tab.

Comment: Ah yep, they were exactly where I expected them to be. I was just running a build with the plist option disabled :P