# How to capture all iOS console logs?

Tags: ios, swift, logging, uikit, cocoalumberjack

Is it possible to capture all the console logs and save them somewhere (in file or uitextview or something like that)?

I am using CocoaLumberjack for logging but we have some 3rd party SDK that will help our team to debug things.

We can only see logs from the SDK in the Xcode while developing.

I would like to "capture" everything when the app is out for testing. I can't use cocoalumberjack or anything else since I don't have access to the SDK source code.

So, TLDR: We have a 3rd party library that has the ability to log itself. But the problem is that QA and beta testers can't see/send us that logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41741076/5329717