# iOS app terminates without any crash logs

Tags: ios, crash

Our app gets terminated around 30 seconds after app launch. After launch, the user may work with the app or just open and stay on any screen without interacting - in any case, the app terminates. There are no UI freezes. It just gets terminated without generating any crash logs. The crash happens in both the devices the user has. No logs present in either of them. Unable to see the crashes in XCode's Organiser too.

Things tried:

- Checked the user's device storage. The user has enough storage in both the devices.
- Searched for logs in Analytics & Improvements → Analytics Data, found nothing. Share With App Developers switch is ON.
- Got the Jetsam logs that were present around the crash time - no mention of our app or any other relevant info.
- Shared a Testflight build so that Apple will prompt to share the crash with the developer. No prompts after crash.

Even if it is any memory issue when crash logs may not get generated, we expected to find useful info in Analytics Data w.r.t the termination or some info in the Jetsam log at least.

Our option seems to be limited to asking the user to connect to a Mac and get device logs to check anything significant around the time the app crashes.

Would like to know if there are any other options to try.

Comment: Make sure the user is sharing logs

Comment: Can you explain? "Share iPhone & Watch Analytics" switch is On in "Analytics & Improvements". Testflight build crash logs were not prompted to share. Anything else to check?

Comment: There is nothing else, that is what I meant.

Comment: Thirst part crash monitoring seem to "catch" more crashes, it might be worth looking into one such as Crashlytics or Instabug

Comment: An IOS app crash without crash logs is usually because it ran out of memory. To test, run the app with memory monitoring on.

Comment: You could also save in a file at the apps document directoly all the errors(stderr) and include a feature so that the user can send you the the custom logfile(s) after the crash(e.g. open an email composer). See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13303081/2894790 for how you can do this. Make sure you log low memory warnings/notifications https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/responding-to-low-memory-warnings.